# Scheme recursion with dotted-tail notation

Tags: scheme, sicp

I am trying to do exercise 2.20 from SICP. It has introduced the dotted-tail notation. Before I can finish the exercise I need help understanding what is wrong with this test program I have written:

```
(define (f . b)
     (if (null? b) '() (cons (car b) (f . (cdr b)))))
```

When I enter `(f 1 2 3)` into the interpreter, instead of getting what I expected which was `(1 2 3)`, I get a "*maximum recursion depth exceeded*" error.

I cannot see what I have done wrong though. `b` is the list `(1 2 3)`, so I should get `(cons 1 (f . (2 3))` => `(cons 1 (cons 2 (f . (3))))` => `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (f . ()))))` => `(1 2 3)`.

I suspect the problem is that the dotted notation only works with define, but I would like to write a recursive function. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dotted-tail notation can be used with `define`, where it means that extra arguments are collected together in a list. With OP `(define (f . b) ;...)`, in a function call like `(f 1 2 3)`, `b` is bound to the list `(1 2 3)` in the function body. You can't use dotted-tail notation in function calls, though.

But just removing the dot from the attempted function call `(f . (cdr b))` will not work, either. The problem is that `(cdr b)` is a list, so after the first recursive call you have `(f (cdr b))` which means that the value which is passed to `f` is the list `(cdr b)`, and this list is collected into another list and bound to `b` in the new function body because of the way the function is defined.

If the initial call were `(f 1 2 3)`, then the arguments would be collected into a list so that `b` would be bound to `(1 2 3)` in the first call. Then `(car b)` would be `1`, and the subsequent call would be `(f (2 3))`. Then the argument `(2 3)` would be collected into a list so that `b` would be bound to `((2 3))` in the second call. Now `(car b)` is `(2 3)`, which is not at all what is desired.

Later in the book `apply` will be introduced, and that provides a way out of the conundrum:

```
(define (g . b)
  (if (null? b)
      '()
      (cons (car b) (apply g (cdr b)))))
```

But, since we do not yet know about `apply`, we must be creative. Another approach is to define a helper function inside of `f` that takes a list argument instead of an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
(define (f . b)
  (define (helper xs)
    (if (null? xs)
        '()
        (cons (car xs) (helper (cdr xs)))))
  (helper b))
```

Now, the recursive calls are to `helper`, which is *expecting* a list argument.

Sample interactions:

```
> (g 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
> (f 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
```